# List index array of items conditional to reference

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two tables in my document looking like this:

**Serial Number Table (in formula : SNT):**

```
Serial Number    Product model
ABCD             1234
DEFG             5678
HIJK             1234
```

**Product Technical Specification (in formula: PTS):**

```
Product model      Power      Labeling
1234               100w       1
5678               600w       0
```

and the goal is to list every serial numbers associated to a product that needs labeling and their product number and power:

```
Serial Number    Product model      Power
ABCD             1234               100w
HIJK             1234               100w
```

So I tried to write my own Index/Match formula and it somehow wont filter the items that shouldn't be labeled. The formula looks like this:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(SNT[Serial Number],MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,SNT[Serial Number])+IF(INDEX(PTS[Labeling],MATCH(INDEX(SNT[Product model],MATCH(INDEX(SNT[Serial Number],),SNT[Serial Number],)),PTS[Product model],0))<>1,1,0),0)),"")}
```

My result is

```
Serial Number    Product model      Power
ABCD             1234               100w
DEFG             5678               600W
HIJK             1234               100w
```

I might have made my match a bit overly complicated but these tables are over different sheets and I do not know any better to see if labeling is 1 or 0. And to be honest, I've been looking around for an explaination of what MATCH(0,1,0) is doing exactly and couldn't find anything. How can the range be 1 and the value looked up 0?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you please use English function names?

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot some EQUIV inthere, my bad, they mean MATCH, I change them right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was an "Inbetween list" (example below) and here's why:

The array formula seems to make any part of it self an array function. So filtering the serial numbers, set in the **Serial Number Table (in formula : SNT):** by the "Labeling" on the line corresponding to the model in the **Product Technical Specification (in formula: PTS)** table was impossible, it just went through the whole **PTS** list until meeting one with corresponding value and called it valid.

Instead, I just listed all *Serial Numbers* and the *Product Model* from the **SNT** and then filled the other attributes columns, including the *Labeling* from the **PST**.

**Inbetween list:**

```
Serial Number    Product Model     Power      Labeling
ABCD             1234              100w       1
DEFG             5678              600w       0
HIJK             1234              100w       1
```

Finaly, I did a regular array formula to filter by the array column value.